# I tried wiritng a code to calculate the mean of sopfr(x), but it doesnt work

Tags: c, mean, primes

[sopfr](https://oeis.org/A001414)

I tried making a code that calculates the mean from sopfr(c) up to sofr(c+i), but when I input the numbers nothing happens

This is the code ive done

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int sopfr(int x);

int main()
{
    int c ,i ,sum1=0, a=0;
    
    scanf("%i",&c);
    scanf("i",&i);
    for(c;c<=c+i;a++)
    {
        sum1+=sopfr(c);
        c+=a;
    }
    float sum2=sum1/i;
    printf("%f",sum2);
    return 727;
}   

int sopfr(x)
{
    int t, n=2, s=0;
    scanf("%i",&t);
    while(t!=1)
    {
        if(t%n==0)
        {
            t/=n;
            s+=n;
            continue;
        }
        n++;
    } 
    return s;
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: `sopfr(x)` is not using `x`. Why is it asking for input?

Comment: `scanf("i",&i);` should be `scanf("%i",&i);` -- it's missing the `%`.

Comment: Are you sure that `sopfr()` works correctly? Confirm that before worrying about calculating the mean.

Comment: I suggest you display a prompt before each `scanf()`. Then you'll see that the reason nothing is happening is because `sopfr()` is waiting for you to enter `t`.

Comment: Another weirdness: `return 727;` in `main()`. What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @Barmar Yes it works correctly

Comment: I don't see how that's possible when it never references `x`.

Comment: @Shawn I like that number

Comment: @Barmar I wrote the code to calculate sopfr in a nother file and it works there

Comment: @Lettever how did you check your `soprfx` function works? Did you test it?

Comment: Your function asks for input and calculates it just for that one value. You need to change it to calculate the sopfr of `x` instead of asking for input.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I first wrote the code in another file and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `scanf()` call and make `t` the function parameters.

```
int sopfr(int t)
{
    int n=2, s=0;
    while(t!=1)
    {
        if(t%n==0)
        {
            t/=n;
            s+=n;
            continue;
        }
        n++;
    } 
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that was not the only problem, I also changed the for loops with `c;c<b;c++`, where b is c+i

Comment: @Lettever so your function as it appeared in your a question worked elsewhere? Hmmm...

Comment: @Jabberwocky correct i had written the code in another file and it worked there